# Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error ( Python Script Automation on Mac)

Tags: python, macos, automation, launchd

I've been trying to automate this python script that goes to my college website and writes the latest notice into a textfile,via selenium. The script works successfully when executed mannually. I'm on MacOs BigSur. After dozens of attempts of trying to automate it via cron. I just read that cron is outdated for the newer versions of MacOS. I've been trying to learn the other alternative i.e. launchd. I've understood the syntax of the plist xml file and have been trying to run it. But whenever, I try to launch it using launchctl bootstrap gui/....I get a Bootstrap failed :5 error. Below is my plist file. Could someone help me out?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//APPLE//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>py.ChowguleNoticeUpdate</string>
        
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>

        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
        <string>source</string>
        <string>/Users/Logan/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/bin/activate</string>
        <string>&&</string>
        <string>python3.6</string>
        <string>/Users/Logan/PycharmProjects/Selenium/ChowguleUpdateNotice.py</string>
        <string>&&</string>
        <string>deactivate</string>
        </array>

        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>3600</integer>

        <key>StandardOutPath</key>
        <string>/Users/Logan/PycharmProjects/Selenium/logfiles/stdout.log</string>

        <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
        <string>/Users/Logan/PycharmProjects/Selenium/logfiles/stderr.log</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: it shows full path to `stderr.log` and `stdout.log` - maybe check these files. They may have more information.

Comment: as for `cron` (at least on Linux). it may run script as different user, with different privileges, in different `current working directory`, etc. and this sometimes can makes problem.

Comment: There are no files (stderr.log and stdout.log) in that directory as the command ( in the terminal) did not run successfully even once. I believe those files are created once the command is executed sucessfully.